# Loop through array in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I'm working with Laravel 5.7 and have been using [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/).

**Expected outcome:**

I want to pass an array to Vue and loop through specific values to dynamically create a chart.

**What I've been trying:**

I have the following array:

```
0 => array:4 [▼
  "order_date" => "2019-04-01"
  "days_remaining" => 29
  "cash_remaining" => 26714.63
  "ratio" => "1.11"
]
1 => array:4 [▼
  "order_date" => "2019-04-02"
  "days_remaining" => 28
  "cash_remaining" => 26184.61
  "ratio" => "1.41"
]
```

I'm passing the array to my Vue component using the [:bind shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) in my blade.

```
:chart-data="{{ json_encode($array) }}"
```

I was reading about [using a sequential for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript), but whenever I try and add a `for` loop, I get an `Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (19:11)` error.

```
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs' 

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: ['chartData'],

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.chartData); // This works
    var length = this.chartData.length; // So does this
    
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['Ratio Value'],

      // This produces the error listed above
      for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ )
      {
        console.log(chartData[i]);
      }

      datasets: [
        // I want to dynamically produce the following
        {
          label: [chartData.order_date],
          data: chartData.ratio
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

The array length is constant at 5, so I *could* just store their values in hidden inputs in my blade template and make use of `document.querySelector`, but this seems clunky and not the best route.

Any advice would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Why not loop `this.cartData` from within `mounted()`? I'm not seeing the problem here.

Comment: Hey @Camilo, first, thanks for the response. That's where I'm struggling - I know I _need_ to loop through the array, I'm just not sure _how_ to do that. Can you post an answer that shows an example? I'm a PHP / Laravel guy - JS is not my strongest suit.

Comment: The question you linked answers that question, you should try using a `for()` inside your `mounted()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Camilo - if it answered the question I wouldn't have asked it. Whenever I answer questions on SO I typically give an example so that people can learn. Isn't that the whole point of the site? To share knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `for()` out of the `renderChart()` call:

```
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: ['chartData'],

  mounted() {
    var length = this.chartData.length;
    var array = this.chartData;

    // Create new arrays to store the data
    var ratioArray = [];
    var labelsArray = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      // Then push our data to the new arrays
      labelsArray.push(array[i] ? array[i].order_date : '');
      ratioArray.push(array[i] ? array[i].mbr : '');
    }

   this.renderChart({
      labels: labelsArray, // Reference our new labelsArray
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Ratio',
          data: ratioArray, // And our new ratioArray
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

You can't call functions when [initializing objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers).

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as accepted as you helped to point me down the right path. I edited it to include the component re: pushing the data to new arrays. Thank you very much for your time today, I appreciate it!